# hyper-V GUEST don't ping with rest of physical network

Tags: networking, hyper-v-server-2012

I have one hyper-V 2012 and two vm running with Windows Server 2012 Standard. My problem is that the VMs don't connect to my network, only the host does. I've been trying everything I could but nothing changed.

Here's what I've done:

- create virtual switch with external network and check "allow management operating system to share this network adapter "
- delete and create new switch
- try setup integration service
- many times check the network configuration
- reinstall network's driver .
- search about solution for that problem , I found people have same problem but nothing help .
- turn off the fireWall
- Connect one of two network ports

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you ping any of the vm host ip addresses?

Comment: have you binded the external vswitch to the right NIC?

Comment: from geust to host ping and vice versa

Comment: I've one vswitch , I'm sure there is no mistake at all .

Comment: Guest is connected right to physical network and it Can Ping to all network

Comment: Never experienced this issue... Try plugging in both NIC's to the switch just in case. Can you take a screenshot of the vswitch config and dump an ipconfig /all (from the vm host)

Comment: Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Switch_1):

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-4C-36-FC
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.251(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.80

Comment: Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connect
n
   
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.61.53(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Comment: If the second ipconfig is your VM then the problem is that the VM has an APIPA ip address and does not have a valid ip address for your "real" network. You've got the vNic configured to use DHCP to get it's ip address configuration but it's unable to find a DHCP server. Do you have a DHCP server on your "real" network?

Comment: Sir . first : the configuration above belong to host just host. second : all VMs have static IP in same subnet for example one of them have static ip 192.168.1.239/24 and GW 192.168.1.254 DNS nothing.

Comment: In my experience the physical NIC shouldn't have IP info as the vswitch just bridges with it.

Comment: What you could try is delete the vswitch temporarily on the vmhost in elevated cmd run netsh int ip reset.. reboot (make sure you only see the physical NIC's in the network connections then once rebooted see if your vmhost can obtain an external DHCP lease (to test connectivity) then recreate the external switch and try again?

Comment: I'll do it but i think that is not the problem

Comment: it's not work ... the host can reach to physical network but guest is not .